# Spring MVC : How to access a model object List<String> in JS?

Tags: javascript, spring, model-view-controller, model, controller

It is supposed to be a trivial knowledge in Spring MVC, but I am stuck in this tricky part.
Obviously I miss something important!

So, I want to:

1. send a List of names taken from the database to the front end
2. add an extra name  in the list *names* (in the controller side)
3. access the list of names in a javascript variable in the jsp file

//controller

```
List<String> names = namesService.getnames(); ("John", "Peter", "John" )
names.add("Nick"); 
model.addAttribute("names", names); 
//JSP
<script type="text/javascript">
    var names = ${names};
</script>
```

What happens next is that the names received from the database ("John", "Peter", "John" ) are recognized in JS as Strings, but "Nick" is recognized as an uknown variable Nick:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Nick is not defined
```

Why is this happening? How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

when you use `${names}` it calls `toString()` method of `names` object  and returns its result. for example consider the following code:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("alice");
names.add("bob");
```

in your jsp you have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var names = [alice, bob]
</script>
```

so it is obvious that alice and bob references are not defined. they must be `['alice', 'bob']`.

so enclose your string with `'` everything should works.

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("'alice'");
names.add("'bob'");
```

Comment: I am just very curious, why doesn't this happen when you populate names from hibernate service? `List<String> names = namesService.getnames(); // ("John", "Peter", "John" )`  ? From java/controller side there shouldn't be any difference when you do  `names.add("alice")`;

Comment: @fatecasino can you provide the source code of your hibernate service? I tested it again using jpa/hibernate the problem still existed, you have to enclose the string with `'`